# Natural isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}V$ and $V\oplus V.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

The title pretty much says it all.

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space, I want to find a natural complex linear isomorphism $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}V \cong V\oplus V.$

I understand how to show that they are isomorphic using dimension but I can't come up with an explicit natural isomorphism.

Please can someone give me a hint?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Morally, we are splitting $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ into eigenspaces for the action of multiplication by $i$; however, this is confusing because there is already an action of multiplication by $i$ on $V$, and we don't mean this action. We can change notation to make the confusing part go away.

Write $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2 + 1)$. Then $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ = $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$. Write $W$ for this vector space.

Now, multiplication by $x$ gives an endomorphism of $W$, annihilated by the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ and not any proper divisor of this polynomial, so it must split $W$ into $\pm i$ eigenspaces, which by counting are each one-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

Consider the map $$c \otimes v \mapsto (\Re(c) v, \Im(c) v).$$ This map is clearly injective and since you have same dimensional vector spaces, it implies that it is also surjective.

Comment: I thought of this map but I didn't think it was $\mathbb{C}$-linear?

Comment: @user350031 it is linear for the complex structure on $V$, not the one on $\mathbb{C}$. (in the language of my answer, it is linear for the action of $i$ on $V$ that was already there before you tensored with a second copy of $\mathbb{C}$, but not for the action of $x$ on $V$.)

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused. Call your map $\theta,$ then it is clearly $\mathbb{R}$-linear since it arises from an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map. However, in order to prove $\mathbb{C}$-linearity we need to show that $\theta((c'c)\otimes v) = c'\theta(c\otimes v)$ right? And this doesn't seem to be the case! Sorry about this...

Comment: @user350031 it depends on how you give $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ the structure of a complex vector space. A priori, there are two ways. What is true is that $\theta(c \otimes c'v) = c'\theta(c \otimes v)$.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this as a separate answer from my other one because it is a little different in flavor; fundamentally these answers are the same, though.

Lemma: There is a natural isomorphism $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$.

Proof: Write the second copy of $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) &= \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)\\
&= \mathbb{C}[x]/((x+i)(x-i))\\
&\stackrel{CRT}{=} \mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i) \oplus \mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i)\\
&=\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}.
\end{align*}

Main result: For any complex vector space $V$, there is a natural isomorphism $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} = V \oplus V$.

Proof: One has
\begin{align*}
V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} &= (V \otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}) \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \\
&= V \otimes_\mathbb{C} (\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C})\\
&= V \otimes_\mathbb{C} (\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C})\\
&= V \oplus V
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: I follow this proof! Thanks! Still confused about the map from Dubussy's answer though.

Comment: @user350031 our maps are different, I was not correct before when I said they were the same.

Comment: I think this proof shows that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} V \simeq V \oplus \overline{V}$, where $\overline{V}$ is $V$ but with the conjugate $\mathbb{C}$ action given by $c \cdot v=\overline{c}v$, because $x=-i$ on the factor $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i)$